# How do I get word indexes for Glove embeddings in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use glove embeddings in pytorch to use in a model. I have the following code:

```
from torchtext.vocab import GloVe
import torch.nn
glove= GloVe()
my_embeddings = torch.nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(glove.vectors,freeze=True)
```

However, I don't understand how I can get the embeddings for a specific word from this. `my_embeddings` only take a pytorch index rather than text. I can just use:

```
from torchtext.data import get_tokenizer
tokenizer = get_tokenizer("basic_english")
glove.get_vecs_by_tokens(tokenizer("Hello, How are you?"))
```

But then I am confused why I need to use `torch.nn.Embedding` at all as most tutorials suggest I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe this is done using `glove.stoi`:

```
sentence = "Hello, How are you?"
tokenized_sentence = tokenizer(sentence)
torch_tensor_first_word = torch.tensor(glove.stoi[tokenized_sentence[0]], dtype=torch.long)
embeddings_for_first_word = my_embeddings(torch_tensor_first_word)
```

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

Here are some reasons why you might want the glove vectors in an `nn.Embedding` layer:

1. You want to fine-tune the pre-trained embedding weights glove provides;
2. You want to pass trainable batches of indices to be embedded into your model;

As the earlier answer mentioned, you can pass the list of word strings(tokens) in via `glove.stoi[word_str]`.

But you set `freeze=True`. So, if you don't plan to retrain the embedding layer, then you'd probably do best with:

**Words -> Vectors**

```
from torchtext.vocab import GloVe
import torch.nn
glove= GloVe()

test_text = ["Hello", "world"]

embedded_text=glove.get_vecs_by_tokens(test_text)
```

**Vectors -> Indices**

```
def emb2indices(vec_seq, vecs): # vec_seq is size: [sequence, emb_length], vecs is size: [num_indices, emb_length]
    with torch.no_grad():
        vs_new_size=-1, vecs.size(0), -1
        vec_new_size=vec_seq.size(0), -1, -1
        word_indices = torch.argmin(torch.abs(vec_seq.unsqueeze(1).expand(vs_new_size)- vecs.unsqueeze(0).expand(vec_new_size)).sum(dim=2),dim=1)
    return word_indices

word_indices=emb2indices(embedded_text, glove.vectors)
```

**Indices -> Words**

```
list_words=[glove.itos[word_indices[i]] for i in range(word_indices.size(0))]
```